# Scala for comprehension for Slick Query

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-2.4

I'm new to Scala and I'm building a Play app to learn Scala and Slick.  The app has todo lists and each list has items.  Each user has multiple lists.  I've written a controller to get the list as JSON, and the JSON includes all the items in the list.

```
  def viewList(id: Long) = AuthenticatedAction.async { implicit request =>
    val userId = request.user.toLong;
    db.run(todoLists.filter(listById(id, userId)).result.headOption).flatMap { list =>
      list match {
        case Some(_) => {
          val json = toJson(list).as[JsObject]
          // Fetch the items in this list and add them to the JSON response
          db.run(todoItems.filter(_.listId === id).sortBy(_.text).result).map { items => 
            Ok(json + ("items" -> toJson(items)))
          }
        }
        case None => Future.successful(NotFound)
      }
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to write this function using a for comprehension?  I have a nested flatMap+map call, so it seems like it should be possible.

Comment: every call to map, flatMap, filter can be rewritten as for comprehension, but do you really need it? This can be more verbose

Comment: That's an excellent question - I'm new to Scala so I don't really know.  I've been told that for comprehension can make things easier to read.

Comment: if you understand the code with higher order functions, I think you don't. May be just for practising or for someone else better understanding, imho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Like this:

```
def viewList(id: Long) = AuthenticatedAction.async { implicit request =>
  val userId = request.user.toLong
  for {
    list <- db.run(todoLists.filter(listById(id, userId)).result.headOption)
    resp <- list.fold[Future[Result]](Future.successful(NotFound)) { _ =>
      val json = toJson(list).as[JsObject]
      // Fetch the items in this list and add them to the JSON response
      db.run(todoItems.filter(_.listId === id).sortBy(_.text).result).map { items => 
        Ok(json + ("items" -> toJson(items)))
      }
    }
  } yield resp 
}
```

Another variant:

```
  def viewList(id: Long) = AuthenticatedAction.async { implicit request =>
    val userId = request.user.toLong
    for {
      list <- db.run(todoLists.filter(listById(id, userId)).result.headOption)
      items <- db.run(todoItems.filter(_.listId === id).sortBy(_.text).result)
    } yield list match {
      case Some(_) => Ok(toJson(list).as[JsObject] + ("items" -> toJson(items)))
      case None => NotFound
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm confused about why I don't need the first call to ```db.run``` now.  Also, is it possible to include the remaining call to map in the comprehension?  I tried adding your rewritten function to my code, but I get a compile error: Controller.scala:79: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.Result
[error]  required: TodoListController.this.Status
[error]           Ok(json + ("items" -> toJson(items)))

Comment: Oh, sorry you need db.run.

Comment: I added the call to ```db.run``` but I still get the type mismatch compile error

Comment: The full compile error is in the comment above.  Line 79 is the line with ```Ok```.  I don't understand why the required type is Status now.  I realise it's probably hard to debug in isolation.  My full project is at: https://bitbucket.org/thelateperseus/todo-play-angular/src/be0ae4aa28cd8122c1dad7488a96d34afea14d83/app/controllers/TodoListController.scala?at=master

Comment: [Future[Result]] was required. Also I added another variant, just for example.

Comment: I like the second variant because it's more succinct.  However, I'd like to retain the NotFound response if the list doesn't exist.  Is there a way to modify it as such?

Comment: I figured out the answer to that question - I just replaced your ```yield``` clause with a match on list.  I do prefer the for comprehension syntax to my original.